# XSLT 1.0: how to go for the "parent" axis

Tags: xslt, xpath, parent

I have a question concerning the performance of an XSLT calling the "parent" axis in an XPATH.
I can call the parent axis using "::*" or I call it using "::" and the name of the element

```
parent::*/MVKE/item/VMSTA='Z2'
```

or

```
parent::item/MVKE/item/VMSTA='Z2'
```

Does it matter performance wise if I use the "*" or if I use the name of the node element? Both work but I was wondering what the difference is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first expression matches *any* element parent. The second expression only matches when the parent is an `item` element. That's the only difference. I can't imagine any significant performance impact, since both node tests can be performed in constant time.

Note this line from the [XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-parent):

> Every node other than the root node has exactly one parent, which is
>   either an element node or the root node.

In practice this means that `parent::*` matches *any* parent except that of the root element.

To demonstrate, consider this simple example document:

```
<root>
    <one/>
    <item>
        <two/>
    </item>
</root>
```

Then:

- `//parent::*` will get you the `root` and `item` elements (every parent node that is an element)
- `//parent::item` will return only the `item` element (the only parent element that is an `item`)
- `//parent::node()` will get you the parent of `root` (i.e. the root node) as well as the `root` and `item` elements

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same, but I doubt that there will be a significant performance difference.

Using the `*`accepts any parent element, using the name will require that the parent has this name or you'll get an empty node-set. Therefore, if one were faster it would likely be the `*` one.

Another option would be to use `parent::node()`, or its short form `..`

Answer (score 0):

What about simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../node()"/>
```

Gives you the immediate parent. Are there,as was the original question performance benefits in one method V another?

Comment: Are you asking or answering?