# XML Oracle : How to extrct parent node value using SQL Query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have below XML data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd">
<labels _FORMAT="Receipt Test" _QUANTITY="1" _JOBNAME="LBL4001">
    <label>
        <variable name= "RECEIVE_DATE">25-APR-2017</variable>
        <variable name= "PO_NUM">12345</variable>
        <variable name= "QTY">1</variable>
        <variable name= "RECEIPT_NUM">128419</variable>
    </label>
</labels>
```

I need to extract value `Receipt Test` for `_FORMAT` using SQL query.

I have written the below query but it is not working as it returns null value.

```
SELECT TRIM (EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '//variable')) FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE (p_xml_content) xml FROM DUAL), 
        TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (xml, 'labels'))) x 
        WHERE UPPER (EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '//@name')) = '_FORMAT';
```

As per requirement this query should return "Receipt Test" value. Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere? (*"Can someone write this for me?"* is not a question.)

Comment: SELECT TRIM (EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '//variable')) FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE (p_xml_content) xml FROM DUAL), 
        TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (xml, 'labels'))) x 
        WHERE UPPER (EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '//@name')) = '_FORMAT';

Comment: I have written the above query but its not working. Please help

Comment: You should add all code to the question (you can always edit your posts). Besides the SQL, also write down what result it currently produces and what result you expect.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, As requested I have edited my post. Thanks

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006929/xslt-1-0-how-to-go-for-the-parent-axis

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking for exactly, but does this help..

```
SQL> with MY_XML_TABLE as
  2  (
  3  select XMLTYPE(
  4  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  5  <!-- <!DOCTYPE labels SYSTEM "label.dtd"> -->
  6  <labels _FORMAT="Receipt Test" _QUANTITY="1" _JOBNAME="LBL4001">
  7      <label>
  8          <variable name= "RECEIVE_DATE">25-APR-2017</variable>
  9          <variable name= "PO_NUM">12345</variable>
 10          <variable name= "QTY">1</variable>
 11          <variable name= "RECEIPT_NUM">128419</variable>
 12      </label>
 13  </labels>') as XMLDOC
 14    from DUAL
 15  )
 16  select XMLCAST(
 17           XMLQUERY('$XML/labels[label/variable/@name=$VALUE]/@_FORMAT' passing XMLDOC as "XML", '_FORMAT' as "VALUE" returning content)
 18           AS VARCHAR2(32)
 19         ),
 20        XMLCAST(
 21           XMLQUERY('$XML/labels[label/variable/@name=$VALUE]/@_FORMAT' passing XMLDOC as "XML", 'QTY' as "VALUE" returning content)
 22           AS VARCHAR2(32)
 23         )
 24    from MY_XML_TABLE
 25  /

XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$XML/LABELS[LA XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$XML/LABELS[LA
-------------------------------- --------------------------------
                                 Receipt Test

SQL>
```

Note I had to comment out the DTD.. To make it work with the DTD you will need to load the DTD into the root of the XML DB repository or issue the following command before executing the query

```
   SQL> -- Turn off DTD Validation
   SQL> --
   SQL> alter session set events ='31156 trace name context forever, level 2'
     2  /
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!! This helped me a lot.